# Why hovering in this menu is not working in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover

When a anchor is hovered in this menu it should turn its background white. It works in Firefox and Chrome but in IE the words just disappear and the background doesn't turn white.

**(the `current anchor link` works in IE is just the `hover` that doesn't work)**

**EDIT:** the `color` property in `a:hover` is working in IE the problem is just the `background-color` property.

Like in the following picture:
[alt text http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/2330/hover.png](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/2330/hover.png)

Here is what happen when I hover a link in IE (in this case 
**espanol**):
[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/4677/spanishn.jpg](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/4677/spanishn.jpg)

CSS:

```
#lang {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 50px 25px 0 0;
    width: 285px;
}
#lang li {
    font-size: 10px;
    float: right;
}
#lang li a#english, #spanish, #chinese {
    color: #FFF;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    width: 200px; /* ie fix */
}
#lang li a#english {
    padding-left: 231px;
}
#lang li a#spanish {
    padding-left: 228px;
}
#lang li a#chinese {
    padding-left: 219px;
}
#lang li a:hover {
background: #FFF;
color: #444;
}
#lang li.current a {
    background: #FFF !important;
    color: #444 !important;
    cursor: default;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="lang">
                <li <?php if($lang_file=='lang.en.php') {echo 'class="current"';} ?>><a id="english" href="index.php?lang=en">english</a></li>
                <li <?php if($lang_file=='lang.es.php') {echo 'class="current"';} ?>><a id="spanish" href="index.php?lang=es">español</a></li>
                <li <?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-tw.php') {echo 'class="current"';} ?>><a id="chinese" href="index.php?lang=zh-tw">中文(繁體)</a></li>
                <li <?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-cn.php') {echo 'class="current"';} ?>><a id="chinese" href="index.php?lang=zh-cn">中文(简体)</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Could you copy and paste the source (view source) for the menu (ul node)

Comment: Have you tried switching to background-color: white; ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#lang li.current a {
    background: #FFF !important; /*!important may be causing the issue*/
    color: #444 !important;      /*!important may be causing the issue*/
    cursor: default;
}
```

also change:

```
#lang li a:hover {
background: #FFF;
color: #444;
}
```

to:

```
#lang li a:hover {
background-color: #FFF;
color: #444;
}
```

Comment: I deleted !important but I'm still having issues with hovering in IE

Answer (score 0):

Try using a background-image instead of just a background color, even if the image is just a white block repeated. I had the same problem, googled and found this, then fixed it using an image ;)